# A question about thermodynamics (endothermic reaction)

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, physical-chemistry

I am probably getting lost in a cup of water but.. better to clarify.

So, my book makes an example of an strong favorable endothermic reaction (so much that the bin [the can] does freeze with all the reagents involved).

It asks to explain how is this possible. And here is where I don't know if I am thinking well.

If I have an endothermic reaction, the enthalpy is then positive, hence in the equation for $\Delta G$, I need to have a negative $-T\Delta S$ and it has to be greater than $\Delta H$.

But $T$ is fixed, hence I have to mind on the entropy that has to be very large.

The entropy does increase as the "disorder" increase (please, just take this). The products are solids (or liquids) and just ONE of the products is actually a gas.

Would it be enough to say that the reaction is favorable because one of the final products is a gas, and a gas does increase the level of entropy? (Because we have sparse molecule that travel fast and chaotically).

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at this fairly basically in two ways.

> Would it be enough to say that the reaction is favorable because one of the final products is a gas, and a gas does increase the level of entropy?

Gases do indeed 'generally' have high Entropy because they are highly disordered. Formation of a gas as a reaction product thus tends to increase $T\Delta S$ and makes the possiblility of a negative $\Delta G$ easier.

Secondly, chemical reaction are *always* equilibrium reactions:

$$A+B\leftrightarrow C+D$$

The equilibrium constant $K$ is:

$$K=\frac{[C][D]}{[A][B]}$$

Where the bracketed quantities are *concentrations*.

Now assume (e.g.) $C$ to be gaseous:

$$A+B\leftrightarrow C(g)+D$$

As the gas tends to separate out (assume it to be insoluble in the reaction medium) then its constant evolution ensures that $[C]$ is always low and this 'pulls' the equilibrium to the right, in order to maintain $K=\mathrm{constant}$. This is known as [Le Chatelier's principle](http://www.chemguide.co.uk/physical/equilibria/lechatelier.html) (aka 'the *mass effect*').

Both explanations are thermodynamically equivalent.